# Any decent scheme implementation that has *no* threading libs?

Tags: multithreading, unix, scheme

I am considering which scheme to use.

I would like to use a scheme that has or can be compiled to have **no threading support**. I have to avoid the layers that threading libs provide. **I want an implementation that has no code for interpreter locks, etc**. Something that can compile to C is ideal. This will be Unix only. Chicken and Gambit are my first choice with TinyScheme as an alternative strategy.

I want to use this scheme as the replacement for a ruby app that I have now. This is why it has to be a *decent* scheme, it has to have rich support for strings, hashes, regex, dictionaries, etc.

Any such beast out there?

Answer (score 0):

You might try [Chibi Scheme](http://synthcode.com/wiki/chibi-scheme) or [Larceny](http://larcenists.org).  I don't think that either of them have threading.  Chibi runs on a VM, Larceny compiles to native code.  I expect that Larceny's support for various libraries will be better.